# Want to transfer information contained in a database in one iteration of an app to another iteration on a different phone

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I consider myself an accomplished programmer, but I'm relatively new to Android App development.   I'm creating an application that will store information into the SQLite database used in Android.  What I'd like to be able to do is be able to take a query of that data and export it either as a file of some sort or just send it to another iteration of the same application on a different phone.   Then be able to have that phone import the same information into its own database, seeing that the information should line up correctly as long as it keeps it.

Can anyone provide some good starting examples of how I would best go about this and/or tutorials on how to go about doing it?  Right now I'm just not sure how to get started and I could use some help to push me in the right direction, so I'd really appreciate the help.

Thank you ahead of time to anyone who replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and export it either as a file

depends on what kind of data you have. You can write any kind of text-based data using a [RandomAccessFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) for example.

> send it to another iteration of the same application on a different
>   phone

You will need to have your own backend to do so. You could identify the target device by using [GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Comment: The data would be from a database query, so I would need to be able to retain its column name as well.  So that when it was imported on another phone it would know where to put the data inside of its own database.  Would the RandomAccessFile be the best way to do that or would you suggest another manner?

Comment: @FadedAce the `RandomAccessFile` is just a java I/O mechanism. It's up to you how to structure the data you are going to write to a file. I'd probably use `JSON` format, since it will allow you to reproduce your database and it is also common so send `JSON` data over the network. Example: Table "Customer" -> `JSONArray` "Customer". Column "oder_id" -> `JSONObject` with key "oder_id" and the actual oder ID as value. And so on. I guess as an "accomplished programmer" you will be familiar with `JSON`, if not - it's pretty easy and there are tons of samples on the net.

Comment: Thank you, that actually helps a lot.   Really appreciate it.